# Hide folder name from address bar but only 1 internal css page link not work

Tags: .htaccess

I want to hide a folder name from Address bar by .htaccess, that means hide myfolder name from: http://www.myweb.com/myfolder/mypage but only 1 internal css page link not work.

I used the below code collected from stockoverflow, Its hide folder name well but a internal page links not work.

Here others css and js link work well also.

> Information: I have 2 css folder. One is root directory and others one
>   is myfolder directory.

Internal page link:

```
All css and js page link like as

<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Try 1:

<link href="../myfolder/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Also try 2:

<link href="http://www.myweb.com/myfolder/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

my htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+myfolder/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (?!^myfolder/)^(.*)$ /myfolder/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: You should share how your pages are linking to image/css resources. How do the links look like when they don't work?

Comment: Why have two css folders? And from which one do you want you style.css file to be retrieved?

Comment: I used two css/js file just for codding easily because I have more then 150+ page. only 1 myfolder/css/style.css not work but myfolder/css/pagination.css and others js file work well.

Comment: Is there a css/style.css file in root folder as well?

Comment: I replace my myfolder/css/style.css in root css/style.css. Its not work also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the following rule only passes the request to files inside `/myfolder` if the request path does not already exist. But, since a `/css/style.css` also exists at the root, the test fails and preempts the rule.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # if not a file
RewriteRule (?!^myfolder/)^(.*)$ /myfolder/$1 [L,NC]
```

The easiest way to resolve this would be to either rename the folder or css file inside the `myfolder` directory. The other way would be to append a query string tag like

```
<link href="css/style.css?myfolder" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

and check for it within the .htaccess like

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^myfolder$ [NC]
RewriteRule (?!^myfolder/)^(.*)$ /myfolder/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Ok sir, I am trying to rename. And let you know.